# Unchecking Checkboxes in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox

For the life of me I can't figure out how set it up.  I would like the function to check the entire sheet... alternatively I do know which specific ranges (B5:B26; G5:G26...AF5:AF26) on a specific sheet, if i can't set it up for the entire sheet...

```
function setFalse()
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Test");
var dataRange = sheet.getRange('A:AN28');
var values = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++)
  {
    if (values[i][j] == true)
    {
      values[i][j] = false; // Modified
    }
  }
}
dataRange.setValues(values);

};
```

Comment: What's wrong with the script? Does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a built-in method to uncheck called [`uncheck()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#uncheck). You can effectively  apply it to the sheet by using [`getDataRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange).

```
function setFalse() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Test").getDataRange().uncheck();
};
```

Lastly, looking at your original code, don't forget to get a [spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html) file before selecting the [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet.html).

Comment: hahaha thank you, of course they would have so many built in methods